# CardView And HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android

Como fazer para todos os *cards* tenham a mesma altura com *scroll* na horizontal?

**Fragment:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/app_bg">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentgone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_title_video"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_title_latest"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/latest_video"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_view2"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
                    card_view:elevation="5dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_more"
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:text="@string/more_btn"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rel_c_content_video"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linear_title_video"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <GridView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/ultimos_episodios"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>   
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

**CardView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
        card_view:elevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/imgsec"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_view2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
                    card_view:elevation="5dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <com.example.util.CatSquareImageView
                            android:id="@+id/image_home"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="1.5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/primary_text_home"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/secondary_text_nome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:text=""
                android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_remove_red_eye_black_24dp"
                android:drawablePadding="8px"
                android:textColor="@color/black_light" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Como a visualização de texto pode ter mais de uma linha, ele acaba quebrando o *layout*.

[image: Card View Image]

Comment: Já tentou alterar o `layout_height` para *match_parent*?

Comment: Já sim, não funciona, estou perdido não sei mais oque tentar.

Comment: Mas qual comportamento você espera que tenha? Limitar o numero de linhas?